# SwiftUI ChildView Not recalculated on state change

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

So this is most likely a newbie SwiftUI question, I have a parent view which takes an @ObservedObject (e.g. viewModel) the view model seems to be correctly publishes changes in the model to the CollectionView, and view is correctly recalculating the body. However, the child view's (`EmojiCell`) body doesn't seem to be recalculated? Below is the related code, appreciate any insight.
I can get this to work, if I change the Card to be ObservableClass and to have its isFaceUp as @Published but this obviously is not the right solution!

```
struct CollectionView: View {
  @ObservedObject var viewModel: EmojiMemoryGameViewModel
 
  init(viewModel: EmojiMemoryGameViewModel) {
    self.viewModel = viewModel
  }
  
  var body: some View {
    // This is called on tap as expected so the viewModel is indeed
    // correctly notifying the view of it's change, the body is
    // recalculated, BUT EmojiCell's body doesn't get called!
    print("CollectionView recalc")
    
    return HStack {
      ForEach(viewModel.cards) { card in
        // This doesn't
        EmojiCell(card: card).onTapGesture {
          viewModel.choose(card: card)
        }
        
        // This works!
//        return  ZStack {
//          if card.isFaceUp {
//            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
//              .fill(Color.white)
//            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
//              .stroke(lineWidth: 3)
//            Text(card.content)
//          }
//          else {
//            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).fill()
//          }
//        }
//          .onTapGesture {
//            self.viewModel.choose(card: card)
//          }
      }
    }
    .padding()
    .foregroundColor(.orange)
    .font(.largeTitle)
    
  }
}


typealias EmojiCard = MemoryGame<String>.Card

struct EmojiCell: View {
  
  let card: EmojiCard
  
  var body: some View {
    print("Cell recalc")
    return ZStack {
      if card.isFaceUp {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
          .fill(Color.white)
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
          .stroke(lineWidth: 3)
        Text(card.content)
      }
      else {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).fill()
      }
    }
  }
}

// Other relevant code
  struct Card: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: Int
    var isFaceUp = true
    var isMatched = false
    var content: CardContent
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
  }
  

extension MemoryGame.Card: Equatable {
  static func == (lhs: MemoryGame<CardContent>.Card, rhs: MemoryGame<CardContent>.Card) -> Bool {
    return lhs.id == rhs.id
  }
}

class EmojiMemoryGameViewModel: ObservableObject {
  
  @Published private var model: MemoryGame<String> = EmojiMemoryGameViewModel.createMemoryGame()
  
  static func createMemoryGame() -> MemoryGame<String> {
    let listOfCards = ["", "", ""]
    return MemoryGame(numberOfPairsOfCards: listOfCards.count) { index in
      return listOfCards[index]
    }
  }
  
  var cards: [MemoryGame<String>.Card] {
    model.cards
  }
  
 
  func choose(card: MemoryGame<String>.Card) {
    model.choose(card)
  }
}
```

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you with your code.It seems that you are unfamiliar with the specifics of `ObservableObjects` there are many things that could be happening `@Published private var` shouldn't be `private` that is what SwiftUI should be referencing put the `listOfCards` there vs referencing a method. In `EmojiCell` `EmojiCard` should be an `ObservableObject` it will never be told to reload. Look at the [Apple SwiftUI tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply, I found the issue with my code, it was actually none of the points you pointed out (which I don't think are valid points).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a silly mistake on my part. The problem was actually immature implementation of Equatable which is actually no longer needed as of Swift 4.1+ (same for Hashable). I originally added it to ensure I could compare Cards (needed for index(of:) method), however, since I was only checking comparing id's, it was messing with SwiftUI's internal comparison algorithm for redrawing. SwiftUI too was using my Equatable implementation and thinking oh the Card actually has not changed!